# SQL Server, what is the optimal Processor & Core configuration for VMs?

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning, vmware, cpu

In my day job I deal with alot of SQL Servers...and lately I've had a rash of clients running 16 cores but configured as 1 core per processor and their SQL Standard edition runs like a dog, as expected.

My question is this: Have you ever looked into what tends to be a better Processor-Core configuration? 1x8, 2x4, 4x4, 4x2, 8x1, etc. I know there are other aspects to this too around NUMA & 24+ cores on enterprise edition, increasing the CPU share in VMWare vs. increasing the CPU core count, etc.

I'm curious if you (or any of your fine friends) have looked into this and what the performance differences may look like as well as test results.

The software I work with typically has a minimum of 8 cores in SQL Server, some clients have 12 or 16, and a rare few outliers run even more.

Additional Details:
-We start Cost Threshold for Parallelism to 50 or 75 depending on the scenario.
-We change MAXDOP to 4 or 8 depending on the scenario.
-We have an army of other changes that we make to SQL Server for best practices (for us).  This question about Processor-Core configuration has never really been dug into that I can recall.

Comment: VMWare provides guidance for running SQL Server on ESX: https://www.vmware.com/solutions/business-critical-apps/sql-virtualization.html  and they deal with NUMA configuration at length here: https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/solutions/sql-server-on-vmware-best-practices-guide.pdf

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Thanks I'll look into it.  Do they get into how many cores per processor should be configured for performance? (put licensing aside for a moment).

Comment: Yes.  And there's some non-performance non-licensing considerations too.  But in general reporting the actual host NUMA configuration to the SQL Server VM and letting SQL Server deal with it is best.

Comment: Hi @mustaccio, while I think the questions are similar, I feel that mine is looking for more actual results than just conversational thoughts.  I've seen two "identical" systems perform wildly different and the other question doesn't really delve into that, it really just says that if the total cores are the same the performance should be the same.